# Reciprocal Solution to the Ramberg Osgood Equation

Tags: calculus, polynomials, diophantine-equations

The Ramberg Osgood equation relates the stress in an elastic plastic material to the strain.

$\epsilon_a=\frac{\sigma_a}{E}+(\frac{\sigma_a}{A})^\frac{1}{n}$

$E$ and $A$ are both bigger than $\sigma_a$

As for $n$ it should be smaller than 1.

The reason I want to solve this equation's reciprocal is because we sometimes obtain $\epsilon_a$ and we need to solve for $\sigma_a$

Any help would be appreciated, because I can't seem to find a way to solve it with my current math tools.

Note: I know this can be solved numerically with countless ways, but I was searching for a closed formula

Comment: Please could you give a numerical example of a solution?

Comment: For example, A=1344 E=200000  n=0.18    Take epsillon=0.0301  You will find that Sigma=700  (I chose sigma then got epsilon but I need the other way around)

Comment: My apologies for the delay. Using $R=\frac{1}{n}$ I can only see a solution for $R=2$, with the possibility of a solution for $R=3$ and the remote chance of a solution for $R=4$. My guess is that this is not what you need.

Comment: No, but I guess my question has no solution